# Node.js while video streaming send JSON data

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, video-streaming, html5-video

I want to stream a local video file and while doing that I want to send some x, y coordinates to the front-end.

I have a following code which can stream a video but how can I send JSON data alongside? I don't want to create another end-point.

```
const express = require("express")
const fs = require("fs")
const app = express()

app.get("/video", (req, res) => {
    const path = "video.mp4";
    const stat = fs.statSync(path);
    const fileSize = stat.size;
    const head = {
        'Content-Length': fileSize,
        'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
    }
    res.writeHead(200, head);
    fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res);
});
 
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('App is running on port 3000')
})
```

Comment: Are you asking for a way to append some json to the video stream? If the json needs to be downloaded intermittently while the user watches the video you could use web sockets to do this while the video streams.

Comment: @JayB yes, but this JSON data is related to the video, I want to draw some bound box and JSON data contains this information

Comment: Surely you could download the json data before the video starts, yeah?

Comment: No need to read JSON data. I will create the data while user is watching. For example, while user sees the first second of the video I need to create a JSON object and send it to the user.

Comment: Yeah IMO you should use socket.io for this.

Comment: Do you have any example or code so that I can check it out?